# KML Region Shapes

Tags: kml, regions

I have found on Google Code page how to create box regions (http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/regions.html).  However I am trying to figure out if I can make a circular region easily.  Basically I have a placemark and I want a certain area around it highlighted with a shaded circle.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want Polygons instead. A Region defines when something is visible or loaded, it's not a geometry. There is no circle primitive in KML, however. You would have to make a circle by making a polygon with many vertices close together.

Comment: Looking at Polygons my same question still applies.  I see how to make a shape based on X many corner points, but I am still looking to make a circle.  Is there any polygon or other option that allows for a center mark and radius or something to create a circle around a single point?